# NHibernate is not fetching Joins

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity that is defined in two tables with fluent nhibernate

```
Table one:
Employee
---------
Id,
Name

Table Two:
Salaries
--------
Employee_Id,
Salary
```

On Fluent NHibernate I defined it like this:

```
EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
public EmployeeMap()
{
   Table("Employee");
   Map(x => x.Id);
   Map (x => x.Name);
   Join ("Salaried", m =>
   {
      m.Map (x => map.Salary);
      m.KeyColumn("EmployeeId");
    });
}
}
```

When I do a Session.Get like the following:

```
Employee e = session.Get<Employee>(employeeId);
```

Then I got all the details of Employee, except the columns coming from the "Salaries" table

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use the HasOne method like so:

```
EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
     public EmployeeMap()
     {
       Table("Employee");
       Map(x => x.Id);
       Map (x => x.Name);
       HasOne(x=>x.Salary).PropertyRef(r=>r.EmployeeId);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Employee is being lazy loaded so NHibernate will only call out to the database if you access the Salary property.

Answer (score 0):

The table and KeyColumn names are wrong in the [join mapping](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/nhibernate-mapping-ltjoingt.aspx). Should be:

Join ("Salaries", m =>
   {
      m.Map (x => map.Salary);
      m.KeyColumn("Employee_Id");
    });